# Generators that doesn't created in R

Tags: r, generator, simulation

Having some difficulties with my code...
I need to create a code that generates the passengers and trains in specific schedules.
In the code below the passengers are created as they should but the trains aren't created at all.
I tried some different possible ways to solve this issue but still haven't found one.
Do you see something I'm missing?

the function inside the train generator:

```r
TrainSchduale<- function(){
  if (now(TrainSim)<9*60){
    return(7*60)
  }
  else{
    return (16*60)
  }
}
```

The generators code:

```r
add_generator("Train", trainTraj,
    distribution = from_to( start_time=  1.5*60, 
                            stop_time= function ()TrainSchduale(), 
       dist = function () 44.99, arrive = TRUE, every = NULL), 
       mon=2)  %>%
  add_generator("RegularPassenger",priority = 0, regularTraj, 
     distribution = from_to(start_time=0, stop_time=16*60, 
     dist=function () exp(0.6912117), arrive = TRUE, every = NULL),
     mon=2) %>%
  add_generator("SoldierPassenger",priority = 1, soldierTraj, 
    distribution = from_to(start_time=0, stop_time=16*60, 
     dist=function () exp(0.513304), arrive = TRUE, every = NULL), 
     mon=2)
```

Comment: Please don't post code in an image. It makes it not searchable and copy/pastable, so then it is harder to help you.

Comment: where is the `add_generator` function from ... ?? (looks like the `simmer` package ?) and what are `trainTraj`, `regularTraj`, `soliderTraj`?  Can we have a [mcve] please ... ?